# A boundary problem for analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, algorithms

The help w/the following boundary problem is needed: Is there an efficient algorithm to check if a closed curve $\Gamma=f(S)$ in the complex plane $C$ is the image of the circle $S$ under a function $f$ analytic inside the circle? (What's known: winding numbers should be non-negative (but it's not enough), and there is a relevant PhD thesis).

Comment: Is there a relationship to Seifert surfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two relevant papers:

1. Titus, C. J. *Characterizations of the restriction of a holomorphic function to the boundary of a disk.* J. Analyse Math. 18 (1967) 351–358.
2. Farias, Antonio O. *Orientation-preserving mappings, a semigroup of geometric transformations, and a class of integral operators.* Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 167 (1972), 279–289.

(The author of 2 was a PhD student of Titus). 
Quote from 1:

> One of the main results, Theorem 1', shows roughly that a holomorphic 
>   function on the disk can map the boundary of the disk onto a regular curve 
>   if and only if there is a differentiable mapping of the disk, with a non-negative 
>   jacobian, which maps the boundary of disk onto the given curve.

The second paper is in [free access](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1972-167-00/S0002-9947-1972-0295374-6/home.html). Quote:

> Theorem 4. Every normal, BL-map is, after a topological change of parameter,
>   a holomorphic boundary.

I'll leave it for you to sort out "normal" and "BL".

Comment: These are great references w/interesting and useful results for me. Thank you @peter. But they do not provide a constructive algorithm for solving the problem. Recalling a thesis by Blanc (may be wrong spelling) that had a relevant combinatorial algorithm. Would be grateful for the reference.